# Spark Standalone Mode: How to compress spark output written to HDFS

Tags: scala, compression, hdfs, apache-spark

Related to my other question, but distinct:

```
someMap.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://HOST:PORT/out")
```

If I save an RDD to HDFS, how can I tell spark to compress the output with gzip?
In Hadoop, it is possible to set

```
mapred.output.compress = true
```

and choose the compression algorithm with

```
mapred.output.compression.codec = <<classname of compression codec>>
```

How would I do this in spark? Will this work as well?

**edit**: using spark-0.7.2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method `saveAsTextFile` takes an additional optional parameter of the codec class to use. So for your example it should be something like this to use gzip:

```
someMap.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://HOST:PORT/out", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

**UPDATE**

Since you're using 0.7.2 you might be able to port the compression code via configuration options that you set at startup. I'm not sure if this will work exactly, but you need to go from this:

```
conf.setCompressMapOutput(true)
conf.set("mapred.output.compress", "true")
conf.setMapOutputCompressorClass(c)
conf.set("mapred.output.compression.codec", c.getCanonicalName)
conf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString)
```

to something like this:

```
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "true")
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK")
```

If you get it to work, posting your config would probably be helpful to others as well.

Comment: with which version of spark does this work? I'm using spark-0.7.2 and I get an error at compiletime: `error: too many arguments for method saveAsTextFile`. I saw that this was [discussed](https://github.com/mesos/spark/pull/645) though.

Comment: I see that it is in the newest spark-0.8.0. Will have to pull it as it seems since this is a rather important feature.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. I've been working with the master branch, not 0.7.2.

Comment: I've tested your second snippet (`System.setProperty(...) [...]`) and it immediately worked with 0.7.2. Thanks :)

Comment: @noah You're setting `spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec` twice, which is redundant unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Wondering whether it is possible to avoid the hadoopish format when storing data to a file. I can't use the directory with `_SUCCES` and `part-*` file. I just need a specifical named single file... I'm using `s3` storage

Comment: Similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933053/spark-writing-dataframe-as-compressed-json

Comment: Is it possible to set thes parameters in a similar manner in `spark-defaults.xml` instead, so every job could use it? I tried replicating the settings into `spark-defaults.xml` but the settings seem not to be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to save gzipped files to HDFS or Amazon S3 directory system is to use the **saveAsHadoopFile** method.

someMap is RDD[(K,V)], if you have someMap as RDD[V], you can call someMap.map(line=>(line, "") to use saveAsHadoopFile method.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

someMap.saveAsHadoopFile(output_folder_path, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[MultipleTextOutputFormat[String, String]], classOf[GzipCodec])
```

Comment: Is it possible to set thes parameters in a similar manner in `spark-defaults.xml` instead, so every job could use it? I tried replicating the settings into `spark-defaults.xml` but the settings seem not to be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

For newer Spark release, please do the following in your spark-defaults.xml file. (`mapred` is derecated).

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec</name>
    <value>GzipCodec</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type</name>
    <value>BLOCK</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

***This is a simplest/shortest way to do compression quickly for all most all versions of the spark.***

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.CompressionType

 /**
   * Set compression configurations to Hadoop `Configuration`.
   * `codec` should be a full class path
   */
  def setCodecConfiguration(conf: Configuration, codec: String): Unit = {
    if (codec != null) {
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true")
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString) // "BLOCK" as string
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", codec)
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true")
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", codec)
    } else {
      // This infers the option `compression` is set to `uncompressed` or `none`.
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "false")
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "false")
    }
  }
```

where `conf` is `spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration`

`codec` String parameter options in the above method are

> ```
>  1.none 
>  2.uncompressed 
>  3.bzip2 
>  4.deflate 
>  5.gzip 
>  6.lz4 
>  7.snappy
> ```